# How to receive the Events from .NET using Python

Tags: python, signalr

I want to consume the events/Signals exposed by the Application via .NET SignalR.
My requirement is to receive those signals using Python.
Kindly help me out.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a SignalR python client from scratch or find if somebody else has written one.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked here:

[Using SignalR server from Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148408/using-signalr-server-from-python-code)

There are no Python SignalR libraries available, so your only option would be to port a lightweight version of SignalR to python yourself. See  https://github.com/davidfowl/SignalR.Lite

Obviously this is not a trivial undertaking!

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to offer another approach. Maybe the simpler solution would be to execute the SignalrR javascript library in python and just create a translational layer to get it back into python objects.

I do not have code proving this, but I was hoping this would encourage someone in the future to try it.